# How do I change the icon of an xterm?

Tags: linux, icons, xterm

`xterm` windows typically don't have an icon. I would like to know what my options are. My immediate need is specifying an icon at `xterm` launch (cmdline argument or Xresource-style), not dynamically changing the icon after the window has been created.

I will post what I've found as an answer, but I hope there will be others with more information than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read that it is possible to associate only `.xbm` images with an xterm. The way that I've found to change the icon for all xterms is:

1. Edit `~/.Xresources` and add a line like:
   `xterm*iconPixmap: /usr/share/doc/tk8.5/examples/images/pattern.xbm`
2. Run the command `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` (this step implies that the path for `.Xresources` is not set in stone :)

An interesting post-launch alternative is [`xseticon`](http://xseticon.sourceforge.net/), which can open `.png` files and set the icon of an existing window.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what tzet has said:

One nice thing I often used is the *active icon* (option +ai) but gnome's metacity doesn't seem to honor the request.

*xterm* then displays a dot for every character on the "screen" - not readable at all one thinks, but if you code `banner READY` at the end of a long running task, this `READY` is readable in the icon.